# symfony 2 twig access array javascript index

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

Is it possible to get object from `twig` array knowing that the index is a `javascript` variable

Mycontroller

```
public function showContactModalAction($iduser, $profil) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $contacts = $em->getRepository("LeymaxContactBundle:User")->findBy(array('accesslevel' => 'arch'));

    return $this->render('LeymaxContactBundle:Default:contactModal.html.twig', array('contacts' => $contacts));
}
```

MyTwig

```
 $(".fils_zone_livre").on('click', function() {
        var index=3;
        var contacts = '{{contacts[index]}}';

    });
```

and I tried also:

```
var contactArray = '{{contacts|json_encode}}';
```

but i get this reponse:

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

as an empty array

Comment: It seems you are looking for an entity serializer instead of `json_encode`. What about [**jms/serializer**](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) to serialize your entities instead of json_encode.

```
var contactsArray = JSON.parse("{{ contacts|serialize('json') }}");
var contact = contactsArray[index];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just needed almost the same as you.

But instead of

```
var contactArray = '{{contacts|json_encode}}';
```

you should use

```
var contactArray = '{{contacts|json_encode|raw}}';
```

Hope this helps.

Hennes

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fils_zone_livre").on('click', function() {
    var index=3;
    var contactsArray = {{ contacts|e('js') }};
    var contacts = contactsArray[index];
});
```

This should work. Twig parses the template on the server, before the javascript is executed, so it can't know about js variables.

Comment: thank you for your answer , i try it but i get this error

Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\LeymaxWeb\app\cache\dev\twig\f9\f1\dcbafef3211e582ab150327ba1c59cbf3008c51290dd41d694c2b2ec9717.php line 245") in LeymaxContactBundle:Default:contactModal.html.twig at line 179.

Comment: The `contacts` var should be JSON encoded. You can use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)