# Unable to access array of entities passed through twig in javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I am currently working on a symfony2.0 project. At the moment I am stuck at some point where I want to use some simple javascript within my twig file.

From my controller I pass an array of entities called `Machine` to the twig file like this:

```
 ...
return $this->render('PRwissHostsBundle:mini:editLocation.html.twig',
       array(
         'form' => $form->createView(), 'id' => $id, 'machines' => $machinesInLoc, 
       ));
```

My form inside the twig file easily cann acces the `machines` array. What I now need is to access this array within javascript.

Currently I m doing this like follwing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    var mach_array = {{machines|json_encode|raw}};
    var machine = mach_array[0];
    alert(machine.name);
    ....
</script>
```

Somehow if I alert the `mach_array` it says that it is an object. Same result when I alert the `machine`. What is not possible is to access the machines id or name or whatevers property of it.

I have searched a couple of other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424742/symfony-2-twig-access-array-javascript-index) but unfortunatly they were not helpfull regarding an array of entities.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you fully print the mach_array so see what's in ?

Comment: I suggest you to use console.log(mach_array) to check your data and with Twigg you can use {{ dump(machines) }} to see what are inside your response.

Comment: if I print mach_array it says `{}`

Comment: Then I think it's more likely to be a query problem. I think `$machinesInLoc` is an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just solved my problem with the help of Nihilnovi. The problemw as not an empty array like gregory supposed, I just did not realy figure out how to properly use javascript and twig entities. The working code now looks like following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function report(period){
  var e = document.getElementById("form_machines");
  var selectValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectText  = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  if (selectValue != ""){
    var table = document.getElementById("uebersicht");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<b>Name:</b>";
    var mach_array = {{machinesAvailable|json_encode|raw}};        

    {% for machine in machinesAvailable %}
      if ({{machine.name|json_encode|raw}}  == selectText){
       cell2.innerHTML = "<a href='{{ url('PRwissHostsBundle_det_machine', { 'id':machine.id }) }}'> {{machine.name}} </a>";
      }
    {% endfor %}

    cell3.setAttribute('align', 'right');
    cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' id=machine.id >";
  }
}


</script>
```

Hope this helps some who steps into the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't let Twig handle the data formatting unless it's absolutely necessary, for example as a response from a AJAX call.

With that said, your issue lies with how you declare the mach_array.

```
var mach_array = {{machines|json_encode|raw}};
```

should be

```
var mach_array = '{{machines|json_encode|raw}}';
```

By not wrapping the call to twig, Javascript will make mach_array a Object, its the same as

```
var mach_array = {"foo" : "bar"}
```

which resolves to a Object.

Comment: if I log the mach-array it just says `{}`.. looks like an empty array

Comment: Then try logging '{{machines|json_encode|raw}}' and see if you get the expected JSON string in your console.